# Send a Notification Message to an Android device using adb from a computer

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

Is there a way to to this? I'm able to see many examples for the other way around (forwarding notifications from Android device to the PC)
Thanks in advance

Comment: As I see it is possible only using Google C2DM! Any other ideas will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C2DM is the only available approach as of writing